# Error - Failed To Access Active Directory Failed to access Active Directory while creating resourse Azure Information Protection

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'am trying to give the hability to my users to be able to sync their Microsoft Edge features (such like bookmarks, passwords,...), over their Azure AD accounts, but I am unable to setup Azure Information Protection, who is a resource that don't come by default.

If I try to create a resource and choose "Azure Information Protection", I go the following error:

`Error - Failed To Access Active Directory Failed to access Active Directory`

Reference documentation that I am following: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/information-protection/configure-policy#to-access-the-azure-information-protection-pane-for-the-first-time

I am a global admin, and all my users are using Exchange Online lvl1 and Teams Exploratory.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have AIP licenses?

Comment: Didnt knew that it was needed a license for AIP. How can I purchase that license?

Comment: If you implement something that requires AIP licenses then you need to purchase AIP licenses. You can purchase them just like you purchase any other Office 365 license. In your tenant go to Billing>Purchase services then select the Security and identity category and find AIP. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/information-protection/configure-policy#subscription-support

Comment: After comparing two O365 tenants, I've notice that in one I dont have the marketplace.. On the other tenant were I've the marketplace, I can check that there is a license per user for AIP Premium P1.

Comment: So seems like in this tentant, this is under that path @joeqwerty, but after that I've to choose "view products", to reach that "Marktplace" ....